# MaterializeCSS Uncaught TypeError: $(...).carousel is not a function

Tags: jquery, materialize

i got this console error while using MaterializeCss framework from https://materializecss.com/carousel.html#one! :

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).carousel is not a function
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (index.html:48:24)
at e (jquery.min.js:2:30038)
at t (jquery.min.js:2:30340)
```

While using jQuery and MaterializeCss framework:

```
<html>
<head>
    <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

    <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="carousel">
        <a class="carousel-item" href="#one!"><img src="http://2.ngsoft.de/E3sAmcr">Hallo</a>
        <a class="carousel-item" href="#two!"><img src="http://2.ngsoft.de/9i7nKEo"></a>
    </div>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.carousel').carousel();
    });

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I think i do not have jQuery loaded twice...

Answer (score 0):

Okay I got it, I just had to load the `jQuery` script before the `MaterializeCss` one... Thats all